# Yii saving many MANY_MANY relationships

Tags: php, forms, activerecord, yii, many-to-many

## Info

I'm having some issues with saving a model that has many MANY_MANY relationships. I have a page where you can add product attributes as well as product attribute levels. What I now want to do is add support for this on the update-page on the product. So when I enter the update-page, I will see all product attributes, and for each product attribute, there will be a drop-down list with the related product attribute levels for that specific product attribute.

## Database

**Product**

- id
- etc

**ProductAttribute**

- id
- etc

**ProductAttributeLevel**

- id
- product_attribute_id ## FK
- etc

**ProductProductAttributeLevel** -- This is the pivot-table

- product_id ## FK PK
- product_attribute_level_id ## FK PK

## ActiveRecords

Product:

```
class Product extends S360ActiveRecord {

    public function behaviors() {
        return array('CAdvancedArBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.CAdvancedArBehavior')
        );
    }

    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('attributeLevels', 'safe'),
        );
    }

    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'attributeLevels' => array(self::MANY_MANY,
                'ProductAttributeLevel',
                'product_product_attribute_level(product_id,product_attribute_level_id)'
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

ProductAttribute:

```
class ProductAttribute extends S360ActiveRecord {

    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'levels' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductAttributeLevel', 'product_attribute_id'),
        );
    }

}
```

ProductAttributeLevel:

```
class ProductAttributeLevel extends S360ActiveRecord {

    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'productAttribute' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProductAttribute', 'product_attribute_id'),
            'products' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Product', 'product_product_attribute_level(product_attribute_level_id,product_id)'),
        );
    }
}
```

ProductProductAttributeLevel:

```
class ProductProductAttributeLevel extends S360ActiveRecord {

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'productAttributeLevel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProductAttributeLevel', 'product_attribute_level_id'),
            'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),
        );
    }

}
```

My ProductController method that updates a product looks like this:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {

    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Product'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Product'];

        if ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }

  $this->render('update', array('model' => $model));

}
```

Relevant part in my form-view:

```
<?php 
    $form=$this->beginWidget('S360ActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'product-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    )); 
?>

<?php $attributes = ProductAttribute::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('survey_id' => $model->parent_id)); if ($attributes): ?>
<div class="span6">
    <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'attributeLevels',
            CMap::mergeArray(
                array('0' => Yii::t('backend','No attribute level')),
                CHtml::listData($attribute->levels, 'id', 'label')
            ),
            array('class' => 'span5')
        );
    }?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

## Issue

I get this CDBException:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`product_product_attribute_level`, CONSTRAINT `product_product_attribute_level_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_attribute_level_id`) REFERENCES `product_attribute_level` (`id`) ON DELE). The SQL statement executed was: insert into product_product_attribute_level (product_id, product_attribute_level_id) values ('5', '0')

Problem is though that product_attribute_level with id "0" does not exist, the id's starts at "1". How would I change it so that it inserts the correct id-number?

## Example of what I want

Let's say I have 2 product attributes; Attribute1 and Attribute2.
Attribute1 have product attribute levels Attribute1_Level1 and Attribute1_Level2.
Attribute2 have product attribute levels Attribute2_Level1, Attribute2_Level2 and Attribute2_Level3.

When I go to my Product edit-/update -page, I want to see this:
[Attributes http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/9252/screenshot20130207at103.png](http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/9252/screenshot20130207at103.png)
[image: Attribute1 Dropdown]

[Attribute2 Dropdown http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/9252/screenshot20130207at103.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/9252/screenshot20130207at103.png)

The Product belongs to a Survey. The Product Attribute's belongs to a Survey as well so fetching all the Product Attributes that the Product *can* have is easy:

```
$attributes = ProductAttribute::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('survey_id' => $product->survey_id));
```

After this I need to fetch all Product Attribute Levels that belongs to each attribute, which is quite easy as well:

```
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

    echo $form->dropDownList($attribute, 'label',
        CHtml::listData($attribute->levels, 'id', 'label'),
        $htmlOptions
    );

}
```

The problem is how to connect it with the Product and have its "$product->attributeLevels" relationship update accordingly based on what I select from the different dropdowns. $product->attributeLevels should be a list of ProductAttributeLevel and should be stored via the table "product_product_attribute_level".

Answer (score 1):

And of course you are selecting from the dropdown? because if not you are indeed sending a '0'

```
<?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'attributeLevels',
            CMap::mergeArray(
                // **HERE**
                array('0' => Yii::t('backend','No attribute level')),
                CHtml::listData($attribute->levels, 'id', 'label')
            ),
            array('class' => 'span5')
        );
    }?>
```

If what you want is to have something as the first option that doesn't represents a record, there are two options, use the `prompt` or the `empty` attributes of [dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail), from the docs:

> - prompt: string, specifies the prompt text shown as the first list  option. Its value is empty. Note, the prompt text will NOT be 
>     HTML-encoded.
> - empty: string, specifies the text corresponding to empty  selection. Its value is empty. The 'empty' option can also be an array
>     of value-label pairs. Each pair will be used to render a list option 
>     at the beginning. Note, the text label will NOT be HTML-encoded.

Now, you want a dropdown list of attributeLevels, but you want them saved on the product. so iterate over the attributes, get its levels, but save them on the product, like this:

```
<?php foreach ($attributes as $i => $attribute) {
        echo $form->dropDownListRow($product, "[$i]attributeLevels",
            CHtml::listData($attribute->levels, 'id', 'label'),
            array('class' => 'span5', 'prompt' => 'No attribute level')
        );
    }?>
```

Now to save them on your product, do this in your controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {

  $model = $this->loadModel($id);
  $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

  if (isset($_POST['Product'])) {
    $attrLevels = $_POST['Product']['attributeLevels'];
    unset($_POST['Product']['attributeLevels']);
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Product'];

    if( $model->save() ) {
      $valid=true;
      foreach($attrLevels as $i=>$attrLevel)
      {
        $pivot = new ProductProductAttributeLevel;
        $pivot->product_id = $model->id;
        $pivot->product_attribute_level_id = $attrLevel;
        $valid=$item->save() && $valid;
      }
      if($valid){
        $this->redirect(array('index'));
      }
    }
  }

  $this->render('update', array('model' => $model));

}
```

*Disclaimer: copy/paste may not work, but you get the idea*

Comment: At first I was like "What is he talking about", because of course I selected something from one of the drop-downs. But not from all(I currently have 3 test-attributes and only selected a level on one of those attributes). Product attributes are not mandatory so users should be able to select "0"(e.g. "No attribute level"). How would I go about to solve that with a form? Essentially what I want to do is only run the attribute update if it's NOT 0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it doesn't work since I need to "group" the attributeLevels belonging to a product PER attribute. For instance, if attribute "Brand" has levels "Fanta" and "Pepsi" and attribute "Size" has "33cl" and "50cl", I want 2 dropdown lists, 1 for "Brand" and 1 for "Size", each list displaying the belonging levels as options. On top of that, I need to be able to select an option from the lists(or leave it blank) and have it update/insert/delete connections in the pivot-table that connects "product" with "product_attribute_level".

Comment: Either you are not making your self clear, or you are not trying the code on the examples nor reading the documentation.

Comment: Most likely you're not understanding what I mean since I both tried your code as well as read the documentation. If I use your code, all attribute's dropdowns(containing their levels) get the same HTML element ID. I solved it via an ugly hack by manually taking care of the form data, it'll have to do for now. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: take a look at [tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table)

Comment: I took a look at it but it seems that it's slightly(but only slightly) different from what I want/need. Or perhaps I don't understand completely how to use it. I updated my original post at the bottom with an example of what I want with pictures as well. Hopefully it will make things more clear!

Comment: I'm assuming my updated post didn't make it any clearer? Or perhaps it's just not possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: I updated the answer, the info was all there, you just need to "figure it out" I added the code that you need, but don't expect to copy/paste it.